# Adding Text Files to My Project

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have developed a VB.NET application that generates code in a specific format.  It has a multitude of features and everything works great.  I recently added the ability to save generated code to a text file as well as the ability to load those text files into the application.  I am looking to add one last feature (perk).  I want to include a bunch of pre-coded text files with the application, that new users can load and use immediately.  As of right now I have the application creating the directory they will go in, but can't find anything on how to include the text files and have them placed in that directory.  This application uses one-click deployment (in case that matters).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First go to solution explorer and click `Show All Files` in the top menu. Then on each file you want to include right click and select `Include In Project`.

After you do that you need to go to properties of the .txt files in the `Properties` window in Visual Studio and set `BuildAction` as `Content`.

Comment: ok, great...so do I have to add them first (like as a reference)?  Thank you!

Comment: Ohhhhh!  Thank you!  That solved it!  I see exactly how that works now.

Comment: Glad I could help. If this solved your issue please check it as answer so that we can help other users that have the same issue. Cheers!

Comment: you got it! One last thing...I included all the files as instructed, but I can't find them after the update.  How can I find out where they were placed (In the solution explorer I placed them in a folder which was also included)  Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean after they are deployed?

Comment: Yes...I only see them in the Projects bin/Release folder but they definitely deployed as they are now in the application folder on the server.

Comment: Do you want to access them programatically? Is that what you mean?

Comment: If you are developing a web application you can access them "~/YourFolder/file.txt"

Comment: No I want the open file dialog to default to that directory...it's a desktop app

Comment: Just an FYI, and thanks again for all the help.  After learning about the huge obstacles clickonce presents, I ended up adding the text files into my resources and reading them into a listbox from a combobox case statement.  It is very clean and functional.  Thanks again.